# Starting iPhone app development in Linux?

Tags: ios, linux

I've heard that you need to get a Mac if you want to develop iPhone apps. Is this true?

Is it possible to develop iPhone apps using Linux? If yes, what do I need and where do I download the necessary tools?

Comment: related http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1056426/iphone-app-development-on-ubuntu

Comment: can someone edit this s/Linux/unix to generalize it?

Comment: @GoodPerson Then you'd be blurring the line between OS X and other OSes, which is what this question is about.

Comment: one of the most important bits of information I ever found. absolutely in-topic, I'd say...

Comment: Great [2017 tutorial by Andy Smith](https://andrewmichaelsmith.com/2017/02/developing-an-ios-app-on-linux-in-2017/)

Comment: https://github.com/kholia/OSX-KVM << Try this repository. I made a BIg Sur KVM in my Ubuntu, it is a little slower than a real machine, but if you tweak a little you can be just fine. I have a 16GB RAM + i5 9900K computer and have done just a little customization at boot (added 12GB RAM and 6 cores to the KVM) - it is usable to deploy an application.

Comment: But if you want to use every day, not only for deploy your IOS app, I would suggest you take a look into Hackintosh and similar.

Comment: For just deployment you can always just rent a Mac and remotely run Fastlane to build and deploy your app.

Answer (score 312):

To provide a differing response, I'm running OS X and Xcode on a virtualised (VMware) machine on Linux.  CPU is a Core2Quad (Q8800), and it is perfectly fast.  I found a prebuilt VM online (I'll leave it to you to find)
Xcode/iPhone development works perfectly, as does debugging via USB to the phone itself.

It actually surprised me a lot - but I've had no issues at all.

Comment: So, using your approach, can you sign and distribute it on iTunes?

Comment: Yep - no problems.  You're using XCode, the signing works fine, I've now got a production app on the store, submitted from the VM. I won't name it for obvious reasons.

Comment: I've got a VirtualBox VM set up that does everything except the USB connection. Hoping I won't have to switch it to VMware.

Comment: its better to buy mac....as i am having performance issue for uuper version of Xcode....when i am running Xcode 4.6...its slowing down my machine

Comment: @Chaos: Could you please post links to what exactly you used to get your setup running?

Comment: Can you also emulate and debug your applications under ubuntu without real iPhone?

Comment: what is the name of "prebuilt VM" that you found online?

Comment: Does this work with virtualbox?

Comment: Could a prebuilt VM be trusted? I mean embedded culprit Softwares, backdoors ...

Comment: Ok. My opinion on this. Once you have the app developed you can use this service to publish http://www.macincloud.com/

Comment: I am also interested in the setup, i use 4gb ram and 4 cores on a ssd but it is still some kind of laggy (but it works)

Comment: Is this legal? I just want to know because even if nothing will happen I still like to do things the "legal" way.

Comment: @Slaknation It's against the license

Answer (score 76):

The answer to this really depends on whether or not you want to develop apps that are then distributed through the iPhone store. If you don't, and don't mind developing for the "jailbroken" iPhone crowd - then it's possible to develop from Linux.

Check this chap's page for a comprehensive (if a little complex) guide on what to do :

http://www.saurik.com/id/4

Answer (score 32):

It seems to be true so far. The only SDK available from Apple only targets the macOS environment. I've been upset about that, but I'm looking into buying a mac now, just to do iPhone development. I really dislike what they are doing, and I hope a good SDK come out for other environments, such as Linux and Windows.

**Obstacles** regarding the SDK:

> #### [The iPhone SDK and free software: not a match](http://www.linux.com/feature/131752)
>
> Apple's recently released a software development kit (SDK) for the iPhone, but if you were hoping to port or develop original open source software with it, the news isn't good. Code signing and nondisclosure conditions make free software a no-go.
>
> The SDK itself is a free download, with which you can write programs and run them on a software simulator. But in order to actually release software you've written, you must enroll in the iPhone Developer Program -- a step separate from downloading the SDK, and one that requires Apple's approval.

I think it's rather elitist for them to think only macOS users are good enough to write programs for their phone, and the fact you need to buy a $100 license if you want to publish your stuff, really makes it more difficult for the hobbyist programmer. Though, if that's what you need to do, I'm planning on jumping through their hoops; I'd really like to get some stuff developed on my iPhone.

Comment: As has been said before, I don't think it's elitism at fault here.  XCode and all the rest of the development tools (with the exception of low-level items such as GCC) are written in Cocoa, as are all the iPhone frameworks.  They'd need to port all this to other OSs first.  That's no small task.

Comment: And even if it is elitism, so what? Need I list other proprietary systems? It's common practice when a product line is first released.

Comment: Let me know when Microsoft release Visual Studio for Linux and Mac...

Comment: Let me know when Microsoft release Visual Studio, Access, Frontpage, XNA, DirectX, Office (with all the features), Movie Maker, Visio, IIS or  Exchange for Mac / Linux.

Comment: Let me know when Microsoft makes it against the EULA to run Visual Studio, Access, Frontpage, XNA, DirectX, Office, Movie Maker, Visio, IIS or Exchange in (Dar)Wine.

Comment: @StephenDarlington letting you know.  Visual Studio has already been released for Linux and Mac.

Comment: @MarceloMason Kind of. It's Visual Studio _Code_, not the full IDE.

Comment: @StephenDarlington letting you know that VS for Mac is a thing already.

Comment: @mr5 that's a marketing thing (rebrand of Xamarin Studio), it isn't the same Visual Studio that's available for Windows.

Answer (score 21):

There *used to be* a project dedicated to solve this defect: [iphone-dev](http://code.google.com/p/iphone-dev)

> The goal of the iphone-dev project is to create a free, portable, high quality toolchain to enable development for the Apple iPhone and other embedded devices based on the ARM/Darwin platform.

Comment: The project doesn't appear to be undergoing regular development or maintenance from the site (e.g. Wiki entries on building the tool / portability are from Feb. 2010).

Comment: @Mr. F, Indeed it's dead.

Answer (score 13):

Regarding the alternative tool chain, Saurik's site is useful but for latest firmware development he indicates building on the iPhone itself and stays clear of indicating that you may need to copy necessary iPhone firmware files to your Linux environment. It's not impossible, but just requires additional work, especially for signing the code (there are open alternative solutions out there as well).

Also, take a look at other guides (for the same tool chain) that approach it more methodically.

I'd suggest to still do the final build and code signing and packaging in XCode (which may mean borrowing someone's Mac) in case you run into problems when submitting the application to Apple. Using the alternative tool chain opens up (at least on the Mac) the possibility of using other IDEs other than XCode for developing the application and again resorting to XCode for the deployment and testing with the simulator.

Of course if you do get the code signing / certificate generation working from the command line outside of XCode then you can install a certificate on your actual iPhone and test there (installing the app via iTunes w/your certificate).

Answer (score 8):

The only way I know of doing development in Linux for the iPhone would be to install Vmware and work on getting OS X running in a virtual machine.  With that said there are some "legal" concerns in doing that.  It is reported that OS X Server can be virtualized but as far as the development story on that I don't know.

If you are truly serious, that's the what I'd investigate.

Good luck.

Comment: I've tried the VMWare option and at least on my hardware (T5200 Core2, 2M ram), it's unusably slow. My friend had a similar experience.

Comment: Me too. Slow, slow, slow. You don't even want to try.

Comment: @Parand Of course its going to be slow on 2M ram, I'm surprised it even boots!

Comment: You might want to try VirtualBox instead of vmware. VMWare is too bloated in my opinion.

Answer (score 5):

You can use [Tersus](http://www.tersus.com/#Id=3215) (open source), and it lets you export the app as an Xcode project.

Comment: `Tersus Studio generates native iPhone applications in the form of Xcode projects that you can compile and sign using Apple's iPhone SDK.`
So it won't be able to complie&sign a native iOS app

Answer (score 5):

You might be able to write code on a Linux box that will eventually find itself on an iPhone or iPad, but ultimately you would need a Mac to test or deploy the code to the iPhone or to submit it to the App store.  So ultimately you need a Mac, so you might as well do the work on the Mac too, with all the tools that Apple provide.  There are alternatives to Xcode & Objective-C, such as Monotouch - but these utilize the Apple tools too.

You can with some work run OS X in a VM on Linux.  However I should point out that this will break the OSX license agreement, even if you buy the copy of OSX - as it is only licensed to run on Apple hardware.

Sorry to give you this news - the ecosystem around the iPhone/iPad is very tightly controlled.

EDIT: One major exception to this is writing a web app for the iPhone.  There are some excellent web apps for the iPhone which are almost as good as user experience as a native app.  However I did interpret your question to be about native app development.  Web apps, although the user can create an icon for launching them - are still 'second class' citizens.

Comment: Although it may be permissible to run Lion in virtualization if you're running Linux on a Mac.

Answer (score 5):

I've had success building iOS apps on linux using the [iOS clang toolchain by cjacker](http://code.google.com/p/ios-toolchain-based-on-clang-for-linux/). Basically it consists of the upstream clang and llvm tools from your linux distro, a linux port of apple's linker and some extra tools to help simplify the build process (such as converting xcode projects to Makefile format).

It does take a few steps to install, but you're a software developer so you'd be used to that. I posted an up to date howto for Debian 7 (Wheezy) online:

https://rogerkeays.com/how-to-build-an-ios-toolchain-for-linux-debian-7

Otherwise you want to go with the generic instructions which are a little older:

http://code.google.com/p/ios-toolchain-based-on-clang-for-linux/wiki/HowTo_en

Good luck.

Answer (score 2):

There's a framework called [Rhodes](http://rhomobile.com/).

The concept is based on Ruby on Rails and you develop your mobile app in Ruby and HTML, and you can write your code in a Linux environment. You can then create an account at [Rhohub](http://www.rhohub.com/), where you add the code (through [GitHub](https://github.com/)), and it allows you to compile it for iPhone, Blackberry, Android, Windows Mobile and Symbian, all off the same code. You don't have to code in Objective-C for iPhone, nor Java for Android, etc. It does the conversions for you. All you need to do is stick to the Rules for creating an iPhone application (or the Phone's you want to develop for) so it can be accepted at iTunes (or the equivalent market).

This will allow you to add the app to iTunes as well.

I have not found any emulators, however, which means that to test your app you need to put it on an iPhone, which is a mission.

I am using this option as I want to create apps for all phones and I use Ruby on Rails already. If you just want to make an app for an iPhone, then invest in a Mac.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

You're right non-jailbroken phones are limited to Apple's App store and Apple "has the right" to enforce whatever rule, it's totally nonfree territory.
However while developing, one won't have to deal with Apple at all. You can use e.g. rsync to upload the code to the device and test it.

Comment: Does this project overcome the problem that Stephen Cox presented? *"You will never get your app approved by Apple if it is not developed using Xcode. Never. And if you do hack the SDK to develop on Linux and Apple finds out"* Thanks

Comment: libmobiledevice actually has a decent interface to install applications without needing rsync/ssh on a iDevice.

Answer (score 1):

I did an attempt to port cocos2d-iphone to GNUstep so that you can *Develop* game based on cocos2d. However for publishing you need a mac. [cocos2d-GNUstep](https://github.com/ANindie/cocos2d-GNUstep).

Answer (score 1):

You need to get mac for it. There are several tool chains available (like win-chain) that actually lets you write and build i Phone applications on windows. There are several associated tutorials to build the Objective C code on Windows. But there is a problem, the apps hence developed will work on Jail broken i Phones only.

We’ve seen few hacks to get over that and make it to App Store, but as Apple keeps on updating SDKs, tool chains need regular updates. It’s a hassle to make it up all the time.If you want to get ready app you can also take help from arcapps its launches apps at a reasonable price.
[iphone app development](http://www.arcapps.com)

Answer (score 1):

To a certain extent, yes, it is possible. You can type Objective-C code and set up your projects. You can even test the C and C++ parts of your code with gcc.

What you cannot do:

- Use Interface Builder to set up your interface, as it's Mac-only. (Not required, but recommended.)
- Compile code that uses Apple's Cocoa classes - they don't exist on Linux.
- Test code in the Simulator - there isn't one for Linux.
- Compile code for real devices or for the App Store - all this requires tools that Apple only provides for OS X.

Comment: when you say that the classes do not exist, what do you mean? I only need the headers, Apple will link it for me anyway. That is how app submission works, AFAIK.

Comment: @JanusTroelsen it means, Cocoa doesn't exist on Linux, and probably never will

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend getting a mac because the ios simulator is amazing for testing in the early stages of an app. But I do know of a small company we work with that develops using Unity so they don't need a load of macs. That way they only need one mac for the office and that's just to compile the final build. It also means it works on android but it really depends on what your building because it's a games engine. You may want to look into web apps using frameworks like Sencha Touch Mobile

Unity: http://unity3d.com/
Sencha Touch: http://www.sencha.com/products/touch/

Answer (score -6):

You will never get your app approved by Apple if it is not developed using Xcode. Never. And if you do hack the SDK to develop on Linux and Apple finds out, don't be surprised when you are served. I am a member of the ADC and the iPhone developer program. Trust, Apple is VERY serious about this.

Don't take the risk, Buy a Macbook or Mac mini (yes a mini can run Xcode - though slowly - boost the RAM if you go with the mini). Also, while I've seen OS X hacked to run on VMware I've never seen anyone running Xcode on VM. So good luck. And I'd check the EULA before you go through the trouble.

PS: After reading the above, yes I agree If you do hack the SDK and develop on Linux at least do the final packaging on a Mac. And submit it via a Mac. Apple doesn't run through the code line by line so i doubt they'd catch that. But man, that's a lot of if's and work. Be fun to do though. :)

Comment: New minis are fine for the task. I think they are about $600 and you can use just about any mouse, keyboard, and monitor. Be sure to calibrate the monitor! XCode seems to run pretty well on my unexpanded mini.

Comment: Xcode runs fine in a Mac OS X virtual machine.

Comment: Apple approves Air SDK apps all the time, zero interaction with XCode. You can do the entire build on linux / windows.

Answer (score -6):

If you value your time, buy a Mac! I don't know enough about Linux development options to offer a viable solution, but it seems the proposed methods involve some pretty roundabout work. If you plan on seriously writing and selling iPhone apps, I think you could easily recoup the cost of a Mac Mini or Macbook. :-)

Comment: Now that there are something like 50,000 apps, it's not necessarily easy to make much. Salad days are perhaps gone.

Comment: @Nosredna I for one like to believe [salad days are here again.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IZ1ljGrlDbw) But seriously, you're right.

Comment: Dude, If we are looking for an alternative for it, it's because buy one is not an available option.