# Can you develop Windows Mobile applications on OS X?

Tags: macos, windows-mobile, cross-platform

Is it possible to develop an application for a Windows Mobile device, on Mac OS X?

This question mostly due to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/276907/starting-iphone-app-development-in-linux/794643#794643), criticising Apple for only releasing the iPhone developer tools for the Mac platform..

I'm simply curious if this is possible or not, hopefully an Apple-vs-Microsoft argument can be avoided! There are similar questions for iPhone-development on Windows ([1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68196/how-can-i-be-a-iphone-application-developer-using-windows),  [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/113547/iphone-development-on-windows), [3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22358/how-can-i-develop-for-iphone-using-a-windows-development-machine)), but not the other way around!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MonoDevelop will run on Mac OS X and according to their [FAQ](http://www.mono-project.com/FAQ:_Technical) it could be possible to create applications for the Compact Framework, but only after running a patcher (mentioned in the FAQ). 
It does look like you wouldn't have any real debug support for the Compact Framework, as you can't install it on Mac OS X and the Windows Mobile emulators can't be used on OS X either.

Answer (score 1):

You can always run Windows virtualized in VMWare, Parallels, VirtualBox or with BootCamp.

Comment: I don't think the Windows Mobile simulator can run in an emulated environment like VMWare/Parallels etc. You have to Boot Camp.

Comment: @SheehanAlam What I meant was that one run Windows (licensed copy of course) virtualized in which one run the *simulator*