# iPhone sdk in Linux

Tags: iphone, linux

I have seen many threads about developing apps for ipod and iphone on linux and windows. I have seen ones saying that you need jailbreak your device, and I have seen ones that say you don't need to, but you don't have an emulator. I have an ipod touch, but I would prefer to not jailbreak it. Is there any possible way to develop for it? I don't plan to submit anything to the app store, but I do hope to be able to debug the things on my device.

Comment: related http://stackoverflow.com/questions/276907/starting-iphone-app-development-in-linux http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1056426/iphone-app-development-on-ubuntu

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to codesign an app such that it can be installed on a current iOS device running the stock OS, you pretty much need an Intel Mac running Snow Leopard plus Apple's iOS SDK tools (or access to such) and an iOS Developer enrollment (or "borrowed" certificates or team membership).