# Developing for iphone under unix

Tags: iphone, xcode, unix, ubuntu

My question is very simple:

- Is there any solution to install xCode, or equivalent, under unix OS, like ubuntu ?

Indeed, i don't want to buy an expensive macbook to develop my private iPhone applications.

Comment: This question is very similar: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/276907/starting-iphone-app-development-in-linux

Comment: Indeed, my appologies :S

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The iPhone SDK requires Mac OS, and you need to install the SDK even if you plan to develop applications with, say, [MonoTouch](http://www.mono-project.com/MonoTouch) or [Corona](http://www.anscamobile.com/faq/).

I don't know if Mac OS can be run as a virtual machine inside Linux. Anyway, you may consider buying a Mac Mini. It is not very expensive and powerful enough for software development.

Comment: Agreed! If you seriously want to develop an iPhone app: Buy a f***ing Mac! It's worth the money...

Comment: Ok, thanks for these answers.
So I think I'm going to buy a f***ing Mac :)

Answer (score 2):

The [OSX86](http://www.osx86project.org/) project might solve your problem. It's not as convenient as buying a cheap Mac, but you can install it on a regular PC and it seems there are ways to install XCode on it.

If you end up buying a Mac, be sure to look at the specs for IPhone development first. If I remember correctly, you need a mac based on an x86 core (such as the Mac Mini) to develop IPhone software.

Comment: A "cheap" "Mac" ? What a paradox !
Hum... even with a mac, I have so many problems with provisioning and keys that I'm no sure that I want to develop under strange installlation :)
Let's see mini-mac prices...

Comment: I meant relatively cheap. It really is if you look at the pricing of a a Mac pro.

Answer (score 1):

xCode without Mac OS is definitely not possible. The real question here is, wether it's possible to install the complete Mac operating system in a virtual environment or not.

Comment: That's not true. Have a look here: http://www.google.de/search?q=Osx86+xcode&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla:de:official&client=firefox-a

Comment: @Adrian: OSX86 is about installing Mac OS X, so I don't see how that's supposed to disprove the claim that installing Xcode without OS X is impossible.

Comment: After reading the FAQ for OSX86, I just noticed that you are right. I was assuming that OSX86 is a stripped-down version of OSX, but this does not seem to be the case (except from TPM support).

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know iPhone development under unix is only possible if you jailbreak your iPhone. Which I would not recommend. You could try to buy a used Intel mac mini to develop for the iPhone.

Answer (score 0):

Last Saturday I tested a very nice soft called... VMware !

So is it possible to install mac OSX leopard on this kind of virtual machine ?

Comment: It's possible, just not legal.

Answer (score 0):

Martin,

I am doing some apps development for an iPhone and I have a Windows 7.  You can install VMWare and install the Mac OS 10.6 through this and load xCode from Mac.  The key is in finding the correct place to download VMWare and Mac OS.

Good Luck.