# Build applications for iPhone using Linux or Windows?

Tags: java, ios, iphone, linux, ubuntu

I would like to build an application (in Java preferably) running on the iOS of Apple's iPhone.
The thing is, that I don't have an Apple computer. I mainly use Linux, and Windows when I have to.

Is it possible to build applications for iPhone using the Linux platform?
What type of software is best to learn the ropes of? Suggestions?

Comment: Related http://stackoverflow.com/questions/276907/starting-iphone-app-development-in-linux http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1372372/developping-for-iphone-under-unix?rq=1 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4995252/apple-ios-ide-for-linux?lq=1 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2604980/is-it-possible-to-develop-iphone-applications-with-java?rq=1 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2050943/how-can-one-develop-iphone-apps-in-java?rq=1

Comment: Take a look at [Codename One](http://www.codenameone.com/), which is a Java based library, which can be compiled to native code which can run on iPhone (Windows Phone, Android, Blackberry (I think)). Remember though, you will always be running behind the latest release, and just like Java in the real world, you may not be able to do everything you want...

Comment: Most realistic are probably the cross-platfrom kits like PhoneGap. But if you are really interested in native apps you'll need to get yourself a Mac mini.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PhoneGap uses html, Titanium uses javascript. Both run on iOS (after jumping through the proper hoops).

I believe you can use the xcodebuild option from commandline to work with native Objective C iOS projects in Linux if I'm not mistaken. If not, you can virtualize a Mac environment to run xcode in full.

Typically, it's best to learn the ropes of the native platform for best results. Most other options will require sacrificing functionality or ease of implementation.

As a last resort, you may be able to install OS X on your PC if you have compatible components. Check out "Hackintosh" for more info on this route.