# Building iPhone app on linux

Tags: iphone

Hi all is there way to build iPhone app on linux without using xcode.I want to make use of ant.

Comment: I think it possible, but the software will only work on a jailbroken phone. May be legal issues.

Comment: This is a duplicate of this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/276907/starting-iphone-app-development-in-linux

Answer (score 2):

No, there is no way to build iPhone apps on anything other than Intel Mac's. Even third party app development kits like appcelerator require the iPhone SDK to be installed in the background

Answer (score 2):

Another solution, but again is not possible to compile without a Mac, is Haxe: http://gamehaxe.com/2009/05/22/haxe-on-iphone-simulator/

Answer (score 1):

You need to have a MAC to install iPhone SDK, even with tools such as MonoTouch (which lets you develop in C# instead of Objective C) you still need MAC for the SDK.

Answer (score 0):

Right now the only way is using [MonoTouch](http://monotouch.net/) but is using C# and is not free software.

Comment: also, you still need a Mac + iPhone SDK for any testing and deployment: "MonoTouch requires a Mac and Apple's iPhone SDK to test on the emulator and deploy on the device"

Comment: You're right, but you can run a Linux in an IntelMac, right? ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can develop and write for the iPhone on linux, but there is no way to compile it to an iPhone app and/or check if your code is working properly.

You'll need a mac for that or MonoTouch as said above.

If you want to create games, you can use [Unity 3D](http://unity3d.com/) but that also is not free software.