# Development of iPhone application in linux

Tags: iphone, objective-c, linux

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Starting iPhone app development in Linux?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/276907/starting-iphone-app-development-in-linux)

I have to develop an iPhone application that is able to transfer real time data from a server to an iPhone.

Some real time data examples are:

- cricket scores,
- stocks,
- etc.

We have been told to develop our project in Linux using Objective C. As I'm completely new to this field, could anyone give me any ideas about how to start the project?

Is it recommended to use Linux?

Comment: Tell your manager that developing iPhone apps on Linux is not an option, and wishing won't make it one.

Answer (score 11):

You'll have to use Mac OSX if you want a sane pipeline. You're also going to need to pick up a book on iPhone development. You can run OSX in VMWare if you want by following the tutorial [here](http://www.progamonth.com/?p=60).

Comment: dont necesaraly "need" to pick up a book

Comment: This is not really an advice that you should give anyone but a hobby hacker working from the basement. Following these instructions works, but is violating the iPhone Developer Program agreement you signed with Apple to publish application on App Store. So Apple can rightfully sue your ass.

Comment: Yeah, sure. They should wait the shipping period before getting started.

Also, jailbroken iPhones are evil, and apple is the best company in the world. Get over yourself.

Answer (score 9):

Start by going back to the project manager and tell them that you need a proper Mac to develop for iPhone.

Any hacks you apply to make this work under Linux will just cost you more money than a Mac mini costs now. Unless you are a slave and work for free?

Also using Linux hacks for commercial iPhone development is a violation of the iPhone Developer Program contract you signed to publish applications on App Store. So your legal department should be signaling the red flag if project manager suggests Linux for iPhone development.

Answer (score 3):

Don't even think of using Linux. You'll waste so much time hacking together a development environment and you still won't be able to get some of the required XCode tools such as code signing. It'll be easier & cheaper to just get even a Mac mini.

Answer (score 1):

No, don't use Linux to develop iPhone apps.  While there are Objective-C compilers available, you won't have access to all the Cocoa libraries, which are the bread and butter of iPhone development.  You'll need a Mac.

Comment: While true, this is distressingly sad.  Apple ships the gcc objc compiler.  GCC can trivially build itself as a cross compiler for all platforms *except* Darwin.  I'm tempted to argue that Apple deliberately broke this feature...

Comment: Uh, no.  The compiler is certainly important, but only a small part in the overall toolchain that comprises the iPhone development environment.

Comment: @Andy: Not really, all Apple's changes to GCC are publicly available, the GCC maintainers choose not to accept all Apple's patches. So it could also be argued that the GCC maintainers deliberately broke the feature. Either way, I assume both parties have equally sane reasons.

Answer (score 1):

Adding to the other comments here discouraging the use of Linux for developing iPhone applications, unless you are targeting jail-broken iPhones, you must have Xcode for signing and provisioning iPhone applications.  Also, you'll have no method for running your code inside of a simulator.  The easiest/cheapest solution is to buy a cheap Mac (a Mac Mini can be had for under $600 using your current peripherals).