# Xcode alternative

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

I wanted to know.., whether there is any alternative to Xcode ?
Im probably looking out for a IDE on Linux.

Comment: Emacs, vim, gedit, joe, they all do Obj-C

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have not been on Linux in a while. But I remember Anjuta being my favorite pick for IDE's.

Anjuta is the only development environment that may do Objective-C, I think KDevelop used to but does not anymore.

You might check out http://www.gnustep.org/ see if they have more information.

But as for developing on the iPhone. Xcode is the only "Official" developer tool for iPhone.

Comment: Emacs does Obj-C, as does vim, but that probably doesn't confer the feature set needed (specifically an SDK).

Answer (score 5):

Unless you are targeting jailbroken iPhones, you must have Xcode for signing and provisioning iPhone applications. You'll need the appropriate Cocoa Touch libraries that are only available on the Mac.  Also, you'll have no method for running your code inside of a simulator. The easiest/cheapest solution is to buy a cheap Mac (a Mac Mini can be had for under $600 using your current peripherals).  Truly, if you're serious about iOS development, you need a Mac (and Xcode).

Here's another similar [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1492378/development-of-iphone-application-in-linux).

Comment: I understand.., there isnt any much better tool than xcode.... 
But since I have limited access to a Mac machine..., I want get hands on experience ...by programming in Objective c..., so... Im trying to work out with GNUStep

Comment: BTW - not dissing GNUStep on Linux - it's neat...  Except if you are targeting the iPhone, GNUStep isn't a direct corollary.  You can conceivably learn ObjC this way, but you'll be learning a substantially different library targeting a different platform. Just be aware that GNUStep (and even Cocoa) != Cocoa Touch / iPhone development.  The language of ObjC is quite easy to pick up - it's the intricacies of the libraries that are the learning curve.

Answer (score 3):

By the iPhone tag you have on your post, I'm assuming you're looking for something to make iPhone apps. As far as I know, Xcode is the only program that includes the SDK.

I would go out and buy a Mac mini, or even an older Intel Mac, just make sure it can run Snow Leopard.

Comment: Exactly.., I have already started with it !!... Since I have limited access to Mac system.., Im thinking of an alternative