# Building iOS apps without mac

Tags: ios

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Starting iPhone app development in Linux?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/276907/starting-iphone-app-development-in-linux)
>   [Development of iPhone application in linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1492378/development-of-iphone-application-in-linux)
>   [Alternatives For iOS Development Under Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4533847/alternatives-for-ios-development-under-windows)

I want to learn how to build iOS apps but I dont really have a Mac with me, (but I can use one for testing and stuff). 
So is there any alternative for Xcode IDE in linux(ubuntu-debain) or windows that could be used to get some sort of similar environment as Xcode ?

I know that we can run Mac in VM, but I dont want to use that(its slow,sluggish and painful to use).

Also If you guys happen to know how to compile Objective-C code on Linux,pls share !

Comment: gcc will compile files ending in .m as Objective-C by default, I believe, but that doesn't really give you what you need to build iOS apps on Linux.

Comment: Actually in that question, the person is asking for alternatives of iOS SDK, but here I want to use iOS SDK only !

Answer (score 0):

I compiled a 4.2 version of the GNU toolchain for 64-bit linux. http://xsellize.com/topic/111034-toolchain-for-ios-42/

Answer (score 0):

The iOS SDK is only available with Xcode, which is only available to use on a Mac. So while you can certainly compile Objective-C with gcc on other platforms, you won't be able to compile and link code that uses any iOS SDK APIs on anything but a Mac.