# How to do iphone development using Linux System?

Tags: iphone, linux

Is it possible to use linux system for iphone development?

If it is then how ?

Any Software / help available ?

Thanks in advance...

Comment: Welcome at Super User! This question *might* be moved to Stack Overflow, but you don't need to do anything for that. So, just to be sure: please do **not** ask the same question at Stack Overflow as well. Success!

Comment: Duplicate of this question, among others: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/276907/starting-iphone-app-development-in-linux

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/276907/starting-iphone-app-development-in-linux)

> The answer to this really depends on whether or not you want to develop apps that are then distributed through the iPhone store. If you don't, and don't mind developing for the "jailbroken" iPhone crowd - then it's possible to develop from Linux.

Check this chap's page for a comprehensive (if a little complex) guide on what to do :

http://www.saurik.com/id/4