# Programming on the iPhone on windows/linux?

Tags: iphone, xcode, ios

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I develop for iPhone using a Windows development machine?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22358/how-can-i-develop-for-iphone-using-a-windows-development-machine)
>   [iPhone development on Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/113547/iphone-development-on-windows)

I really, really want to program this application I have onto my iPhone/iPod Touch but I don't have a Mac. I have heard of DragonFireSDK but don't have enough money for the program(does anyone have a beta/trial version of the program?). Please Help. I have ubuntu linux & windows 7 installed.

Comment: possible duplicate of [iPhone development on Windows](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/113547/iphone-development-on-windows), [Best windows iphone app development alternative](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2642877/best-windows-iphone-app-development-alternative),  [How much of an iPhone app can be developed and tested on Linux?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2178571/how-much-of-an-iphone-app-can-be-developed-and-tested-on-linux), [How to do iphone development using Linux System?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1741675/how-to-do-iphone-development-using-linux-system)

Comment: please search for a question before asking, in case someone else has already asked. In this case, this question is asked over and over.

Answer (score 1):

You can always make a "Hackingtosh" - run Mac OSX on Normal PC hardware. Not sure if this is against Apple's EULA or any other license agreement. Just google for it and you will find a lot of guides.

Monotouch actually costs money, as far as i remember - so you probably do not want to use that.