# iPhone dev on Linux

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios-simulator

Actually I have read about that I can write Objective-C app on Linux (using GNUStep).
But my question is, Am I will be able to develop completely iPhone app on Linux machine?
Or I'll need eventually need to use Mac machine?
Especially when I read that there are some some syntax diffs between NeXT/Apple and GCC (according to http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Objective-C)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short answer - yes it can be done but is not as easy as the Mac way.

Duplicate of [how-much-of-an-iphone-app-can-be-developed-and-tested-on-linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2178571/how-much-of-an-iphone-app-can-be-developed-and-tested-on-linux), which will lead you to still more links, and 75-100 others.

Answer (score 0):

I'd try giving VirtualBox and a Mac OS X guest a shot. Some people say they've been able to run it.
http://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?t=2076

If you manage to run it, then you could install X-Code and things should be a lot easier.

Comment: That would be development on Mac OS X, albeit virtualised.