# iPhone SDK install into Linux

Tags: iphone, iphone-sdk-3.0

Can I install the iPhone SDK on a Linux platform?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Starting iPhone app development in Linux?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/276907/starting-iphone-app-development-in-linux)

Answer (score 1):

No, it requires a Mac. Specifically, a Mac with an Intel chip, running Mac OS X 10.5 or later.

See *[iOS SDK](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IOS_SDK)*.

Comment: There are some *very* convoluted methods to compile code for the iPhone on linux.  I would not say that any of these really qualify as "installing the iPhone SDK on linux".

Answer (score 0):

You can install GNUStep, which provides an SDK similar (though not identical) to Mac OS X. With GNUStep, you should be able to write application using at least the Foundation framework with Objective-C, but UIKit will not be available.

To this end, there is no way to install the iPhone SDK on Linux without installing Mac OS X into a Virtual Machine and then using that -- this, however, violates the terms and conditions you agreed to when creating a developer account with Apple.

Answer (score 0):

To download the 3.2 version of SDK at this point of time , requires Snow Leoperd (10.6.2 or above ).