# Developign x-platform mobile apps on ubuntu

Tags: iphone, android, symbian

I'm a junior iphone developer and got familiar with developing on **xcode** on top of Mac OS.
I wanna build some **Cross-Platform apps** in the near future and wanna Use **Ubuntu** as my Operating system.
I found many solutions that run only on Mac OS or need mac to build apps for iphone but this is not what i need . i need something which can keep me far from mac (for some reasons).
I heard about AIR packager for iOS and that also AIR does apps for android but i'm not a flash guy (but can learn if it will do the job), so i wanna guidance from experience people like you about what is the suitable route should I take.

Thanks in advance

Comment: possible duplicate of [Starting iPhone app development in Linux?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/276907/starting-iphone-app-development-in-linux)

Answer (score 1):

I think you may want to build web apps instead. They are written in JavaScript, HTML and CSS. There are some frameworks out there, e.g. [Unify](http://unify.github.com/unify/). That one is using PhoneGap, so you are able to use native functionality in your web app, too. It might still be required to have a Mac to build the iOS package, but apart from that this would be the way to go.