# IDE for iPhone app developing under Linux

Tags: iphone, linux

Is there any IDE and emulator for developing iPhone apps under Linux ?

Comment: FYI: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/iphone+linux

Comment: +1 - Don't know why/who dinged this question - so I up-oned you.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Starting iPhone app development in Linux?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/276907/starting-iphone-app-development-in-linux)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No. You need Mac OS X Snow Leopard running to install the newest version of Xcode and the iOS SDK. There is no IDE or emulator for other operating systems.

Answer (score 0):

No. The iPhone SDK is tightly coupled with the underlaying OS features. So you can't run it on other platform. It is somewhat similar to "How VC++ linked with MFC"

Answer (score 0):

There is actually look at QT Creator
[digia link](http://qt.digia.com/)