# Apple iOS IDE for linux?

Tags: objective-c, linux, ios, ide

I am interested in getting to know whether there is an IDE to develop for Apple iOS? I am currently learning Objective-C, but I don't have a Macbook or something like that.

So actually I am looking for an "all around" IDE, including:

- Objective-C compiler
- Objective-C debugger
- Possibilities to test developed apps (like an iPhone emulator)

What else would I need to develop iPhone apps on Ubuntu (if that's possible)?

Thank you for any suggestions.

Comment: The Apple operating system is "iOS".  "IOS" is Cisco router software.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

What you are asking for is neigh impossible. The only solution I could think of to develop on Linux would be to use GCC or Clang to compile Objective-C. There are no Apple Frameworks or simulators, save GnuStep, and that isn't 100% compatible.

There are a few problems.

1. The iOS SDK libraries don't exist for Linux.
2. The simulator does not exist for Linux.
3. How do you plan to sign your app from Linux?

You could technically use a VM, but that is against the Mac OS X EULA. Another sketchy option is to compile against GNUStep and test on a jailbroken device.

Honestly, your best bet is to break the bank and get a Mac (Mini or Air, now that the MacBook is discontinued. That said, you might consider spending a bit more on a larger screen. It's really hard to write code on just 11 inches of screen.) A few moths of developing may make back your initial investment.

Good luck!

Comment: Instead of a laptop, one can buy the much cheaper Mac Mini.

Comment: you can always dual boot linux/other OSs on your Mac Mini as well... and BYOKDM (bring your own keyboard display mouse)

Answer (score 5):

While probably not producing native looking apps, there are a couple cross-platform multimedia  tool-stacks, like the [Kivy Project](http://kivy.org) - which supports packaging for iOS - http://kivy.org/docs/guide/packaging-ios.html - This project does use Python as the programming language, not objective C.

Comment: You can package a Kivy project on computer with MacOS X only and you should use XCode for it

Answer (score 1):

Take a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/276907/starting-iphone-app-development-in-linux) for info on this. Basically, running a virtual machine with an OSX image is likely to be the best approach if you'd like to distribute your app through the Apple store.