# how to develop apps for iPhone or iPad in Linux Environment?

Tags: iphone, linux

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Starting iPhone app development in Linux?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/276907/starting-iphone-app-development-in-linux)

Is it possible to develop applications for iPhone and iPad in Linux Environment? If yes, can anyone provide some resourceful links for learning how to and some instructions too. And if not then why?