# I Have A project developed using XCode on MAC OS,How Could I build it On Linux?

Tags: iphone, linux, xcode, macos, gcc

I Have A project developed using XCode on MAC OS, for some special reason, I want copy entire project to the Linux operating system and go on developing on linux.

How can I develop and build it on Linux?

I am developing an I-Phone project, I using iOS libraries, I (*wish to*) develop and build on linux, run on iphone

Comment: which language are you using and how much of Apple's libraries?

Comment: I am developing a Iphone project, I using iphone os libraries,and I develop and buile on linux,run on iphone

Comment: possible duplicate of [Starting iPhone app development in Linux?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/276907/starting-iphone-app-development-in-linux)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, it is not currently possible to build **Native** iOS applications using the native Cocoa Libraries and Objective-C on platforms other than Mac OS X.

Answer (score 0):

You have two issues.

First, are you using OS X only libraries, for example Foundation or AppKit? You could potential develop a Cocoa program on OS X and build it against OpenStep on Linux, but at this point you would need to be very selective in which functionality you use, to the point where it is probably impossible.

Assuming that you have fully cross-platform code, then yes you can build it on Linux, but you will need to move away from the Xcode build system. You can create an Xcode project using an external build system, and then proceed to use something like scons, ccmake, or even make. That way the same build files with work both on OS X and Linux. Or you can continue to use the Xcode build system on OS X and keep a parallel build tool for use on Linux.

Comment: I am developing a Iphone project, I using iphone os libraries,and I develop and buile on linux,run on iphone

Comment: As stated in the other answer; that is not possible.