# How to compile objc code on Linux?

Tags: objective-c, linux, compilation

Assuming you have your `.h` and `.m` ready on a Linux server, which command would you issue to `GCC` to have it compiled?

Comment: Just a heads up: you cannot compile code that uses Apple's Cocoa classes.  I recommend reading this post: [Starting iPhone app development in Linux?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/276907/starting-iphone-app-development-in-linux)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The relevant parts:

```
gcc -c -Wno-import List.m

gcc -o prog -Wno-import List.o main.o -lobjc
```

> . . . make sure that the Objective-C library and header files (objc/Object.h) were installed when gcc was built.
>
> Note that when linking Objective-C with gcc, you need to specify the Objective-C library by using the -lobjc switch.

See this [link](http://www.cs.indiana.edu/classes/c304/ObjCompile.html) for more information.

Additional [link](http://ubuntuforums.org/archive/index.php/t-828015.html) with possible solution to the missing compiler issue:

> Try installing either gobjc++ or gobjc

```
sudo apt-get install gobjc++
```

Comment: For RHEL, try the gcc-objc or gcc-objc++ package via yum.

Answer (score 4):

```
gcc -x objective-c file.m -o out
```

Google is your friend

Comment: Comes back with `gcc: error trying to exec 'cc1obj': execvp: No such file or directory` Is there some setup that needs to happen prior to this?

Comment: Try to install "gobjc" package, this should fix the problem.