# iPhone tester for Linux/Ubuntu

Tags: php, iphone, ios, linux

We are converting our website to mobile view (iPhone), but we have no iPhone yet. I need an iPhone tester that should work on Linux platforms as we are working on LAMP.

I found these articles on Stack Overflow:

1) [Starting iPhone app development in Linux?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/276907/starting-iphone-app-development-in-linux)

But it is describing how to develop iPhone app in Linux - I don't want to install these heavy application in my system. I just need an testing environment.

2) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1839719/iphone-beta-tester-platforms

Comment: You need a tester with an iPnohe with jailbreak, isn't it?

Comment: @user1213334 Whatis jailbreak? I need to run a tester in ubuntu linux

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://testiphone.com/

http://iphonemonsta.com/free-iphone-browser-simulator-for-windows-linux-mac

This may be of use.

Answer (score 0):

If you want a quality solution, you want Apple's simulator, or better, the device itself.

Since the device is not available in your case, I suggest you [virtualize](http://www.webupd8.org/2010/07/run-mac-osx-in-virtualbox-under-linux.html) Mac OS X, install XCode and use the simulator.