# how can I compile iOS project on a server

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode

I'd like to be able to do automatic builds of latest code for my iOS project. Any way to do so on a server side on a linux server, for example?

Comment: Is this project for stock OS iOS devices?  Or iOS devices running a modified OS?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must use an OS X-based machine to compile an iOS project.  This can be automated using the command-line Xcode tools (xcodebuild in particular).

Answer (score 0):

The only supported workflow requires OSX, but if you'd rather spend effort than money, some alternatives exist: [Starting iPhone app development in Linux?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/276907/starting-iphone-app-development-in-linux)

Answer (score 0):

You could use Jenkins http://jenkins-ci.org/. We use it at work to build projects once someone has committed something to SVN. It's really handy. There are also a bunch of plugins you could use.