# Can I test/develop an App without having Xcode?

Tags: android, ios, xcode, debian, react-native

I'm really excited to see React Native available but I don't have an Apple device of any kind around and I am used to coding on Debian-based systems.

Is it possible to test the app locally and then once I get a Mac to do the run the build process?

Also, anyone knows when the Android version will be available?

Comment: According to [this thread][1], you can developp without any mac.


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/276907/starting-iphone-app-development-in-linux

Answer (score 4):

It's not officially supported but you should be able to. The app delegate has a path that points to a JS server:[react-native/Examples/SampleApp/iOS/AppDelegate.m](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/v0.2.1/Examples/SampleApp/iOS/AppDelegate.m#L29).

If you point that URL to your Debian machine before building to your phone, it should work. (Of course, the JS should get bundled into the app before submission to the App Store.)

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately you can't do that for now.
It supports only iOS devices and you need XCode in order to test in the simulator because following the documentation (http://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/getting-started.html#content), it's going to create an XCode project

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately you can't.
If it's because you don't have an apple computer you can always try running one on a virtual machine.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a rough outline of what you would need:

1. An iDevice
2. A colleague who will put a build on that iDevice whose root react native bundle points to some endpoint you can control. e.g. `jsCodeLocation = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://mydomain/index.ios.bundle"];`
3. Compile your react app to that location.
4. Run the application on the iDevice, which will do so by downloading the js bundle.

This flow would be considerably inferior to developing on a mac though, as there would be virtually no capacity for debugging, the setup would be a pain, and you would need to restart the application on the device every time.